# HTML: Can't enable button by onclick

Tags: html

I want load a disabled button by default but change it to enable on click the button. Here is how I did it.

```
<button id="Btn" class="navBtn" disabled onclick="enableBtn()">click to enable</button>

function enableBtn() {
   document.getElementById("Btn").disabled = false;
}
```

But it is not working....

I've tried to load an enabled button by default and click to disabled, but the reverse is not working...

I'm using HTML and JavaScript

Comment: You cannot click on a disabled button. Thus the click event won't fire.

Comment: oh!  so if I need to inter change this button status by click I have to put the click event at another place right?

Comment: Yes. Or wrap a HTML element around it.

Comment: Got it! Thank you!

Comment: provided an answer to help you. I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to click on a disabled button. The button is disabled, so it can't be clicked.

Why are you trying to make it so that you have to click to activate it in the first place? Maybe there is a better solution to the problem as a whole?

**Edit:** The actual purpose of the button is to toggle a boolean, this can be done fairly easily like this.

```
var enableFeature = false;

function toggleFeature(){
    enableFeature = !enableFeature;
    (put code setting the feature's status to enableFeature here)
}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_booleans.asp

Comment: I basically trying to turn on/off of some feature and use this button to control it. I thought I can use button enable/disable to record the feature status. Maybe I need to think another way.

Comment: Oh, if that's the case, just create a variable where you store the true/false of whether it should turn the feature on or off and make the button toggle between them.
Do you need me to make some example code for you?

Comment: Thank you! I'll try it. It would be nice to know how to use a button to  toggle between true/false. What I have in my mind now is using if statement.

Comment: My example technically works the same as if you would use an if statement, though it just cuts out the middleman and sets the variable to the opposite of what it currently is!
I've also added a link to an explanation on booleans.
Good luck, hope this helps!

Comment: @user3408259 If this answer has answered your question, please accept it so the question can be closed as answered. If not, please give more information on what still isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code -

```
//html 
<button id="Btn" class="navBtn" onclick="enableBtn()">click to enable</button>

//js
function enableBtn() {
document.getElementById("Btn").setAttribute("disabled", "false")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A disabled button cannot trigger the click method, you should better add a CSS class which makes the button look like disabled.

Here is an example:

```
    <style>
     button.inactive {
       border: 1px solid #999999;
       background-color: #cccccc;
       color: #666666;
     }
    </style>

    <button id="Btn" class="navBtn" onclick="toggleBtn()">click to enable</button>

    <script>
    var buttonEnabled = true;
    function toggleBtn() {
      if（buttonEnabled){
         document.getElementById("Btn").className = "navBtn inactive"
      } else {
         document.getElementById("Btn").className = "navBtn";
      }
      buttonEnabled = !buttonEnabled;
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it by adding a wrapper around it that listens to a click event to enable the underlying button.

```
<div id="btnWrapper"  onclick="enableBtn()">
  <button id="Btn" class="navBtn" disabled>click to enable</button>
</div>
```

However, this approach requires a CSS addition: [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) which is well supported on desktop browsers. Here is the CSS I added to your button:

```
#Btn {
  pointer-events:none;
}
```

This allows you to enable your button when clicking on it.

Life example:

```js
function enableBtn() {
  console.log('button enabled');
  document.getElementById("Btn").disabled = false;
}
```

```css
#Btn {
  pointer-events:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="btnWrapper"  onclick="enableBtn()">
  <button id="Btn" class="navBtn" disabled>click to enable</button>
</div>
```